# Understanding issues - Max of two number without using branching

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

At [**this link**](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) the solution to the problem of finding the max of two number without branching is given.

```
r = y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1))); // min(x, y)
r = x - ((x - y) & ((x - y) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1))); // max(x, y)
```

For the above solution, there are some bugs/limitations mentioned. I want to clearly understand the same. Please elaborate the below points-

1. In what condition it will result in the overflow?
2. Why typecasting to `signed` and `unsigned` required?

Comment: You should paste all relevant text from the linked page into your question.

Comment: Both questions are explicitly answered on that page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is answered in the link

Comment: @harold: Please quote the text from the link that explicitly states in which condition overflow will occur.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "Randal E. Bryant alerted me to the need for the precondition, INT_MIN <= x - y <= INT_MAX"

Comment: @harold: That states there is a need for a precondition but it does not state why. So it is not an explicit answer to the question of what condition will result in overflow. (Things you figure out but that are not completely spelled out are not explicit. The reason learners ask about them is that they are **not** apparent to them, even if they seem simple to you.)

Comment: Be aware that, according to C standard, signed integer overflow even is undefined behaviour!

Answer (score 2):

Overflow occurs if `x` exceeds `y` by more than `INT_MAX` or `x` is less than `y` by more than `INT_MIN`. For example, if `INT_MAX` is 32767, `x` is 32760, and `y` is −20, then the mathematical value of `x - y` would be 32780, but that is larger than 32767, so overflow occurs.

A proposed fix is to replace `x - y` with `(unsigned) x - (unsigned) y` because unsigned arithmetic is done modulo the word size (such as modulo 65536 for 16-bit `unsigned`). Unsigned arithmetic thus produces a result with the same bit pattern as if two’s complement signed arithmetic had been performed with no overflow.

Note there remain some issues with the shift. The `>> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)` is intended to produce all 0 bits (for positive `x-y`) or all 1 bits (for negative `x-y`) by doing an arithmetic shift right of one fewer than the number of bits in an `int`. However, once we have converted to `unsigned`, the shift will be logical (inserts 0 bits) rather than arithmetic (copies the sign bit). And, even if we convert back to signed `int`, the C standard does not guarantee an arithmetic shift.

An alternative is:

```
r = x - ((unsigned) x - y & -(((unsigned) x - y) >> sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1));
```

This performs the shift using `unsigned` (which produces 0 or 1) and then negates it (which produces all 0 bits or all 1 bits).

The result of the entire expression on the right-side of the `=` is then converted to the type of `r`, which is `int`. If it is negative, the result is implementation-defined. At this point, though, we may have to accept some implementation-dependent behavior. The whole point of this bit-hack is to work around a performance issue in some hardware, so the entire motivation for wanting it is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Aconcagua: Something is necessary, but converting back to signed is not actually sufficient since the C standard does not guarantee the desired result is produced. I will add some text. I think a shift (while still unsigned) followed by a negation is better. The shift will produce 0 or 1 (essentially the high bit from `x-y`), and the negation will then produce all 0 bits or all 1 bits.